# Swift Encode/decode emojis

Tags: swift, encode, emoji

I'm trying to encode and decode Emojis to send them to my database.

I use this to encode:

```
var comentario = String()
let data = Comment.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)
if let data = data {
    let emojiString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
    comentario = emojiString
}
```

And it works. But now I don't know how to decode the emoji.

This is the type of encode --->  \ud83d\ude1a

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://gist.github.com/NarayanaRao35/3a69527a746e6cd688c21838e38e2e21) out?

Comment: Because Im not able to touch the server side, so if they are using one type of encoding I need to do the same :/

Comment: Thanks Jose it help me your link

Comment: If you want to answer your own question then post the solution as an *answer,* not as an edit to the question. I have therefore taken the liberty to undo your last edit.

Comment: done, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 29):

Your encoding code can be simplified to

```
func encode(_ s: String) -> String {
    let data = s.data(using: .nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)!
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

Note that it encodes *all* non-ASCII characters not only
Emojis (as `\uNNNN` where `NNNN` is the hexadecimal code of the Unicode character, or as `\NNN` where `NNN` is an octal code). Decoding is done by reversing the transformations:

```
func decode(_ s: String) -> String? {
    let data = s.data(using: .utf8)!
    return String(data: data, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
}
```

This returns an optional because it can fail for invalid input.

Example:

```
let s = "Hello ."
let e = encode(s)
print(e) // Hello \ud83d\ude03.

if let d = decode(e) {
    print(d) // Hello .
}
```

Of course you can also define the code as extension methods of the
`String` type, and you might want to choose better function names.

Comment: Working well.. Thanks

Comment: "Note that it encodes all non-ASCII characters as \uNNNN, not only Emojis". Wrong, it encodes "ç" to "\347"

Comment: @CharlyLafon: You are right. I have adjusted the wording. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. If you have a server with encode utf8mb4, then for encoding emojis use this code:

```
var comentario = String()
let data = Comment.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)
if let data = data {
    let emojiString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
    comentario = emojiString
}// comentario contains the emoji encoded
```

DECODING:

```
let data = comentarios.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

    if data != nil{
        let valueunicode = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue) as? String

        if valueunicode != nil{
            comentarios = valueunicode!
        }
    }//comentarios contantes the deecode string(emoji)
```