# Convert UTF-8 (Bytes) Emoji Code to Emoji icon as a text

Tags: swift, emoji

I am getting this below string as a response from WS API when they send emoji as a string:

```
let strTemp = "Hii \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81"
```

I want it to be converted to the emoji icon like this -> `Hii`

I think so it is coming in UTF-8 Format as explained in the below Image: [Image Unicode](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)
[image]

> I have tried decoding it Online using  [UTF-8 Decoder](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode)

And i got the emoticon Successfully decoded

**Before Decoding:**

[image]

**After Decoding:**
[image]

But the issue here is I do not know how to work with it in Swift.

I referred following link but it did not worked for me.

> [Swift Encode/decode emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220794/swift-encode-decode-emojis)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220794/swift-encode-decode-emojis

Comment: @DávidPásztor: No, those methods work to decode `\uNNNN` escape sequences, but not for this one.

Comment: @Abhirajsinh Did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already given the link of converter tool which is clearly doing `UTF-8` encoding and decoding. You have `UTF-8` encoded string so here is an example of `UTF8-Decoding`.

**Objective-C**

```
const char *ch = [@"Hii \xF0\x9F\x98\x81" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decode_string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ch];
NSLog(@"%@",decode_string);
```

> **Output:** Hii

---

**Swift**

I'm able to convert `\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81` to  in `SWift`.
First I converted the hexa string into `Data` and then back to `String` using `UTF-8` encoding.

```
var str = "\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81"
if let data = data(fromHexaStr: str) {
     print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
}
```

> **Output:**

Below is the function I used to convert the hexa string into data. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502285/1140335).

```
func data(fromHexaStr hexaStr: String) -> Data? {
    var data = Data(capacity: hexaStr.characters.count / 2)
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
    regex.enumerateMatches(in: hexaStr, range: NSMakeRange(0, hexaStr.utf16.count)) { match, flags, stop in
        let byteString = (hexaStr as NSString).substring(with: match!.range)
        var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)!
        data.append(&num, count: 1)
    }

    guard data.count > 0 else { return nil }

    return data
}
```

***Note:*** Problem with above code is it converts hexa string only not combined strings.

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION: SWIFT**

I have done this by using for loop instead of `[0-9a-f]{1,2}` regex because this will also scan `81, 9F, Any Two digits number` which is wrong obviously.

For example: `I have 81 INR \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81`.

```
/// This line will convert "F0" into hexa bytes
let byte = UInt8("F0", radix: 16)
```

I made a String extension in which I check upto every 4 characters if it has prefix `\x` and count `4` and last two characters are convertible into hexa bytes by using `radix` as mentioned above.

```
extension String {

    func hexaDecoededString() -> String {

        var newData = Data()
        var emojiStr: String = ""
        for char in self.characters {

            let str = String(char)
            if str == "\\" || str.lowercased() == "x" {
                emojiStr.append(str)
            }
            else if emojiStr.hasPrefix("\\x") || emojiStr.hasPrefix("\\X") {
                emojiStr.append(str)
                if emojiStr.count == 4 {
                    /// It can be a hexa value
                    let value = emojiStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\x", with: "")
                    if let byte = UInt8(value, radix: 16) {
                        newData.append(byte)
                    }
                    else {
                        newData.append(emojiStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
                    }
                    /// Reset emojiStr
                    emojiStr = ""
                }
            }
            else {
                /// Append the data as it is
                newData.append(str.data(using: .utf8)!)
            }
        }

        let decodedString = String(data: newData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return decodedString ?? ""
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
var hexaStr = "Hi \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81 81"
print(hexaStr.hexaDecoededString())
```

> Hi  81

```
hexaStr = "Welcome to SP19!\\xF0\\x9f\\x98\\x81"
print(hexaStr.hexaDecoededString())
```

> Welcome to SP19!

Comment: Can you please share Swift code for the same. I am not known to obj-C.

Comment: Let me try! Please wait!

Comment: Waiting for the Conversion from your end

Comment: Yes, I'm trying. Actually didn't notice this is for swift.

Comment: You could try Swiftyfy. It's pretty OK when you're trying to translate ObjC code to Swift. https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Any suggestion to make the it decode if it includes texts like "Welcome to SP19!\\xF0\\x9f\\x98\\x81".

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore Actually this is time consuming task and not able get the enough time but I guess you got enough hint to make it done. You need to filter the hexa string. Also please see another answer he already did the job using `"[0-9a-f]{1,2}"` regex.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore as it is very easy in `Objective-C` so can not you use `BridgingHeader` and make a function then use it in swift?

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore Please check the final swift solution updated in my answer. It will work for all string.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore Would you please accept any answer ?

Comment: @TheTiger Thanks a ton for your help. It really helped me a lot. Have approved your answer with a up vote also . Thanks for your hard work

Comment: i was using  [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8] instead of stringWithUTF8String. apparently they're not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I fix your issue but it need more work to make it general , the problem here is that your Emijo is Represented by `Hex Byte` `x9F`  , so we have to convert this Hex to `utf8`  then convert it to `Data` and at last convert data to `String`

Final result `Hii`   **Please read comment**

```
 let strTemp = "Hii \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81"


            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9a-f]{1,2}", options: .caseInsensitive)
            // get all matched hex  xF0 , x9f,..etc

            let matches = regex.matches(in: strTemp, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, strTemp.count))


            // Data that will hanlde convert hex to UTf8
            var emijoData = Data(capacity: strTemp.count / 2)

            matches.enumerated().forEach { (offset , check) in
                let byteString = (strTemp as NSString).substring(with: check.range)
                var num = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16)!
                emijoData.append(&num, count: 1)
            }

            let subStringEmijo = String.init(data: emijoData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            //now we have your emijo text   we can replace by its code from string using matched ranges `first` and `last`

            // All range range of  \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81 in "Hii \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81" to replce by your emijo

            if let start = matches.first?.range.location, let end = matches.last?.range.location  , let endLength = matches.last?.range.length {

                let startLocation = start  - 2
                let length = end - startLocation + endLength

                let sub = (strTemp as NSString).substring(with: NSRange.init(location: startLocation, length: length))

                print( strTemp.replacingOccurrences(of: sub, with: subStringEmijo))
              // Hii 

            }
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the Answer, It helped me a lot, But the thing is it is working for a static string "Hii \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81". What if i get dynamic string in my response. Like "Welcome to SP19!\\xF0\\x9f\\x98\\x81" in this case the emoji is being printed but the app is getting crashed at replacing sub string. any solution to this to making it dynamic.?

Comment: App crash is done because `subStringEmijo` is nill check it, this code is general , you just need to refactor it

Comment: The app gets crashed at let sub = (strTemp as NSString).substring(with: NSRange.init(location: startLocation, length: length)). If i get some other string

Comment: yes, i told you the idea , you need to configure it , you need to get-all ranges of your encoded emijo and replace by decoded emijo

Comment: Thanks For the Suggestion sir. Have up Voted the Answer for your hard Work.