# How to decode \\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099 in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, character-encoding

I am getting following characters:

```
\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099
```

from server side and I want to decode this into its correct character which is "`" so please let me know how I can do this in swift.

I don't want to use replace string method as I want a generic solution which should work for all unicode to string conversion.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with Unicode code points in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift)

Comment: Are you sure the correct character is the backtick? (\`) `\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099` is just `â`...

Comment: "located in the heart of Wanchai\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099s Star" this is a string which is coming from the server and how would I know whether this string contains unicode characters or not so let me know which encoding I should apply on this to get the correct string. Yes this is backstick because in android it is showing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Encode/decode emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44220794/1187415)

Comment: If possible show bytes when dealing with encoding problems. Also, if the server is sending the file via an HTTP response, what does the Content-Type header say, if present?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `"\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099"` the string of 18 characters, you have to unescape it to convert these sequences to their actual values.

This is a possible way to do it:

```
let input = "located in the heart of Wanchai\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099s Star"
let str = String(data: input.data(using: .utf8)!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
```

This gives `"located in the heart of Wanchaiâs Star"`.

As has already been said, `"\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099"` represents a `"â"`.