# Passing unicode emoji from REST API to Android and iOS consumers

Tags: android, ios, api, emoji, unicode-string

What is the most suitable unicode format as string to pass from my REST API to Android and iOS consumers making sure the emoji will display with the least amount of effort by the app developers?

This is my icon.
https://emojipedia.org/fishing-pole-and-fish/

And my API payload:

```
{
    "icon": "U+1F3A3"
}
```

So above emoji can be expressed in a variety of ways:

- `U+1F3A3` From the Unicode website
- `\U0001F3A3` Unicode escape sequence
- `\u{1F3A3}` Unicode scalar
- `0x1F3A3` Hexidecimal

Or can I simply pass it like this?

```
{
    "icon": ""
}
```

Comment: do you see this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228490/5909442)?

Comment: That didn't answer my question.